# comprimir imagen antes de subir - php

Tags: php

buen dia, como hago para comprimir una imagen ates que me suba al servidor, he intentado agregar el codigo para comprimirla pero no funciona, en el código adjunto mi script para comprimir la imagen antes de subirla pero no funciona, si alguien me puede colaborar se los agradeceria.

//code

```js
<?php

$txtNombre=(isset($_POST['valor_t2']))?$_POST['valor_t2']:"";
$txtFoto=(isset($_FILES['txtFoto']["name"]))?$_FILES['txtFoto']["name"]:"";

include ("conexion/conexion.php");
      
      $sentencia=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO empleados(valor_t2,foto) VALUES (:valor_t2,:foto)");
      $sentencia->bindParam(':valor_t2',$txtNombre);
      
      $Fecha = new DateTime();
      $nombreArchivo=($txtFoto!="")?$Fecha->getTimestamp()."_".$_FILES["txtFoto"]["name"]:"default.jpg";
      $tmpFoto = $_FILES["txtFoto"]["tmp_name"];
      if($tmpFoto!=""){
          move_uploaded_file($tmpFoto,"Imagenes/".$nombreArchivo);
      }
      
      //codigo que intente agregar para comprimir la imagen pero no funciona
      ////////////////////////////////////
     function comprimirImagen($recurso, $destino, $calidad) { 

   $imgInfo = getimagesize($recurso); 
   $mime = $imgInfo['mime']; 
 
  //Creamos una imagen temporal
  switch($mime){ 
case 'image/jpeg': 
    $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($recurso); 
    break; 
case 'image/png': 
    $imagen = imagecreatefrompng($recurso); 
    break; 
case 'image/gif': 
    $imagen = imagecreatefromgif($recurso); 
    break; 
default: 
    $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($recurso); 
  } 
 
  // Guardamos la imagen
  imagejpeg($imagen, $destino, $calidad);  

comprimirImagen($_FILES["txtFoto"]["tmp_name"],'',80);
      
      ///////////////////////////////////
      
      $sentencia->bindParam(':foto',$nombreArchivo);
      $sentencia->execute();
      
  
?>
```

Comment: Estás reduciendo la imagen después de subirla, ¿es eso lo que realmente buscas, subir, reducir y guardar? ¿O realmente quieres reducir antes de que llegue al servidor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$txtNombre=(isset($_POST['valor_t2']))?$_POST['valor_t2']:"";
$txtFoto=(isset($_FILES['txtFoto']["name"]))?$_FILES['txtFoto']["name"]:"";

include ("conexion/conexion.php");
  
$sentencia=$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO empleados(valor_t2,foto) VALUES (:valor_t2,:foto)");
$sentencia->bindParam(':valor_t2',$txtNombre);
  
$Fecha = new DateTime();
$nombreArchivo=($txtFoto!="")?$Fecha->getTimestamp()."_".$_FILES["txtFoto"]["name"]:"default.jpg";
  $tmpFoto = $_FILES["txtFoto"]["tmp_name"];
  
  //codigo que intente agregar para comprimir la imagen pero no funciona
  ////////////////////////////////////
 function comprimirImagen($recurso, $destino, $calidad) { 

    $imgInfo = getimagesize($recurso); 
    $mime = $imgInfo['mime']; 

      //Creamos una imagen temporal
    switch($mime){ 
      case 'image/jpeg': 
          $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($recurso); 
          break; 
      case 'image/png': 
          $imagen = imagecreatefrompng($recurso); 
          break; 
      case 'image/gif': 
          $imagen = imagecreatefromgif($recurso); 
          break; 
      default: 
          $imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($recurso); 
    } 

   // Guardamos la imagen
  imagejpeg($imagen, $destino, $calidad);  
  }
  
  comprimirImagen($_FILES["txtFoto"]["tmp_name"],$nombreArchivo,80);
  
  ///////////////////////////////////
  
  $sentencia->bindParam(':foto',$nombreArchivo);
  $sentencia->execute();
  
?>
```

la forma de usar es la siguiente, **comprimirImagen()** recibe 3 argumentos, el primero es la ruta temporal de la imagen, el segundo la ruta del archivo destino con la modificación realizada, el tercero es la calidad con la que quieres que se comprima, sugiero que pongas no menos de 70%

ejemplo de uso

```
comprimirImagen($_FILES["txtFoto"]["tmp_name"],'c:/images/nuevaimagen.jpg',80);
```

Comment: como lo aplicaría al algoritmo que ya  tengo?

Comment: tienes que copiar la función en tu codigo, posteriormente usarlo como te explico en el ejemplo de uso

Comment: intento añadir el codigo que me envias pero no me funciona, actualice el codigo de mi pregunta

Comment: modifique mi respuesta para que pudieras entenderla mejor usando tu propio codigo

Comment: pero la imagen me la esta dejando por fuera de la carpeta Imagenes y quitastes el codigo "if($tmpFoto!=""){
          move_uploaded_file($tmpFoto,"Imagenes/".$nombreArchivo);
      }"

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que comprimas la imagen antes de subirla al backend o sea en el frontend, en el javascript, puedes usar este ejemplo
[Aqui se muestra un ejemplo de como hacerlo](https://img.ly/blog/how-to-compress-an-image-before-uploading-it-in-javascript/)
Luego tendras que agregar el blob en el FormData y enviarlo, asi en el backend recibiras una imagen comprimida

Comment: todo lo tengo en php y quiero solucionarlo con php